# how to Invoke jQuery function while unchecking a check box

Tags: jquery, events

**HTML**
There is a html check box. I cant edit any thing in this code. In default it's checked through an external script.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping[same_as_billing]" id="shipping:same_as_billing" value="1" onclick="shipping.setSameAsBilling(this.checked);">
```

**jQuery**

I have written custom jQuery to show some form elements, when user uncheck the above check box.

```
<script>
    function showForm(){
        code to show a form goes here
     }
</script>
```

**What I need:**

How to call the *showForm()* function when a user uncheck the above check box?
When a user check this back, it shouldn't be invoked.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery. All you have posted is plain JavaScript.

Comment: Best practice is to avoid inline js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to escape the colon in your id and used the "is" method of jQuery to check if your checkbox is checked or not.

```
$('#shipping\\:same_as_billing').change(function() {
    if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
        alert('worked');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwv55/1/)

Comment: Or just `if (!this.checked)`. Avoids a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function, together with the [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Try this:

```
$("#shipping\\:same_as_billing").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    showForm();
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't mention anything about a dynamically rendered checkbox, though. In his question, the checkbox is defined statically in the page's HTML

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').on('change', '#shipping:same_as_billing', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
//CALL YOUR FUNCTION OR WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO 
}})
```